# WSO2 Identity Server managing users and roles through API

Tags: api, wso2, user-management, wso2-identity-server

I need to create and manage users in WSO2 Identity Server 3.2.3 through API, I've tried the code sample from http://blog.facilelogin.com/2010/05/managing-users-and-roles-with-wso2.html but is out of date. Is there any way of managing users and roles without the WSO2 user interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All management services in WSO2 Carbon, have been exposed as Web Service API. For user management, you can use UserAdmin API,  where you can do all management functions related to users and roles in the user store. Please find the sample for UserAdmin API from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/people/asela/wso2-samples/user-manager/user-admin-client/). README file contains more details for you.