# Is there any way to create customized tree in ldap under wso2 Identity server

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am new to wso2. I have a requirement for creating customized tree **(like dn: dc=ravitech,dc=com instead of using dn: dc=wso2,dc=org)** for authenticating the user with ldap under wso2 Identity Server. Currently I saw the following tree structure in LDAP (wso2 Identity server's) through Apache Directory Studio.

dn: ou=example,**dc=wso2,dc=org**
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: example

## people entries

dn: uid=rpurimitla,ou=example,**dc=wso2,dc=org**
objectClass: top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
cn: rpurimitla
sn: rpurimitla
uid: rpurimitla
userpassword:: ZktjUUdmVmFPbXlncHRMcE5jWUVXSDV3iRIHih==

==============

**but my requirement is**

dn: ou=testproject,**dc=ravitech,dc=com**
ou: testproject
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit

## people entries

dn: uid=rpurimitla,ou=testproject,dc=ravitech,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
sn: rpurimitla
cn: rpurimitla
uid: rpurimitla
userpassword: ZktjUUdmVmFPbXlncHRMcE5jWUVXSDV3iRIHih==

please anybody can give the right solution creating our own dn like 
"**dn: dc=revitech,dc=com**" instead of using **dn: dc=wso2,dc=org**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I understood your problem it needs to be created a new partition
this will help:
http://vvratha.blogspot.mx/2011/10/creating-partitions-in-apacheds.html
http://hasini-gunasinghe.blogspot.mx/2011/07/how-to-created-new-partition-in.html

Comment: Thank you johannes, I configured apacheDS as external ldap in wso2 IS successfully, But I have a problem to authenticate users in apacheDS. I can't find any API or sample client program in wso2 IS or Web searching. If you know please give me the sample client or any API it would be great.

Comment: @ravi purimitla as far as I understood your question is that you are looking for a client to accesss the IS from outside? The IS is coming with a service which you can use, here is a thread which is discussing the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11155984/wso2-identity-server-managing-users-and-roles-through-api. In general it would be nice if you vote for the right answer, I saw you are posting a lot of questions but never giving any feedback. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @johannes, it is helpful to me I successfully authenticate external ldap users in client code. Thanks again...